# How to change background colors between user input and computed output in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Pretty new to javascript and jquery so I don't know if it's possible, but here goes. I'm attempting to build a simple chatbot feature for a website. Basically you click the help button link, a chatbox appears with a prompt for input. User inputs and a response comes out accordingly. I've got all this working fine.

What I want is to change the text color or background color of the user:"text" or help:"text" which alternate between chatting. Once the chatbox fills with back and forth text it becomes more difficult to differentiate between user input and feedback. Ideally i'd like the background color of chatbox feedback to be a gray color while user remains white.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
    <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
        <a id="helpBtn" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Help<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <div id="helpBox">
            <span id="usrText"></span>
        </div>
        <input id="textarea" placeholder="Type Here" maxlength="15">
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS/jquery**

```
$(function() {
    $('#helpBtn').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('#helpBox').toggle();
        $('#textarea').toggle();

        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $('#usrText').html('');
            $('#usrText').append('HelpBot: What can I help you with? ','<br />'+'Please type "sales", "info" or "contact" for information.','<br />');
        }
    });
});

$(function() {
    $('#textarea').keydown(function() {
        var text = $(this).val();

        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            $(this).val('');
            $('text').css({
                "background":"blue",
                "color":"red"
            });
            $('#usrText').append('User: '+text,'<br />');
        }
        else {
            return;
        }
        if (matches(text)==1) {
            $('#usrText').append('HelpBot: Todays sales are: ','<br />');
        }
        else if (matches(text)==2) {
            $('#usrText').append('HelpBot: Find info here: ','<br />');
        }
        else if (matches(text)==3) {
            $('#usrText').append('HelpBot: Call: or Email: ','<br />');
        }
        else {
            $('#usrText').append('HelpBot: I did not understand that. ','<br />');
            $('#usrText').append('Please type "sales", "info", or "contact". ','<br />');
        }
        return false; 
        $('#helpBox').scrollTop($('#helpBox').children().height());
    });
});

function matches(text) {
    var a1 = ['sales','sale','bargain'];
    var a2 = ['info','information','411'];
    var a3 = ['contact','number','email','phone'];
    var split = text.split(" ");

    if (a1.includes(text)) {
        var match = a1.includes(text);
        return 1;
    }
   else if (a2.includes(text)) {
        var match2 = a2.includes(text);
        return 2;
   }
   else if (a3.includes(text)) {
        var match3 = a3.includes(text);
        return 3;
   }
}
```

Here's the jsfiddle for the program: 
[JSfiddle Chatbot](https://jsfiddle.net/shanewilson007/oer9cb3n/)

Comment: use css and #usrText { background:blue;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you well, you want to change background color of HelpBot message? If that is the case then just add `<span style="background-color:lightgray;">`Your Text`</span>` and do it like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#helpBtn').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('#helpBox').toggle();
    $('#textarea').toggle();

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $('#usrText').html('');
      $('#usrText').append('<span style="background-color:lightgray;">HelpBot: What can I help you with? </span>', '<br />' + '<span style="background-color:lightgray;">Please type "sales", "info" or "contact" for information.</span>', '<br />');
    }
  });
});

$(function() {
  $('#textarea').keydown(function() {
    var text = $(this).val();

    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      $(this).val('');
      $('text').css({
        "background": "blue",
        "color": "red"
      });
      $('#usrText').append('User: ' + text, '<br />');
    } else {
      return;
    }
    if (matches(text) == 1) {
      $('#usrText').append('<span style="background-color:lightgray;">HelpBot: Todays sales are: </span>', '<br />');
    } else if (matches(text) == 2) {
      $('#usrText').append('<span style="background-color:lightgray;">HelpBot: Find info here: </span>', '<br />');
    } else if (matches(text) == 3) {
      $('#usrText').append('<span style="background-color:lightgray;">HelpBot: Please call: (555)555-5555.', '<br /></span>', '<span style="background-color:lightgray;">HelpBot: Or you can email us at: wookiesRus@weirdos.net</span>', '<br />');
    } else {
      $('#usrText').append('<span style="background-color:lightgray;">HelpBot: I did not understand that. </span>', '<br />');
      $('#usrText').append('<span style="background-color:lightgray;">Please type "sales", "info", or "contact". </span>', '<br />');
    }
    return false;
    $('#helpBox').scrollTop($('#helpBox').children().height());
  });
});

function matches(text) {
  var a1 = ['sales', 'sale', 'bargain'];
  var a2 = ['info', 'information', '411'];
  var a3 = ['contact', 'number', 'email', 'phone'];
  var split = text.split(" ");

  if (a1.includes(text)) {
    var match = a1.includes(text);
    return 1;
  } else if (a2.includes(text)) {
    var match2 = a2.includes(text);
    return 2;
  } else if (a3.includes(text)) {
    var match3 = a3.includes(text);
    return 3;
  }
}
```

```css
#helpBtn {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#helpBox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#textarea {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -23px;
  display: none;
}

#usrText {
  line-height: 1.4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
  <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
    <a id="helpBtn" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Help<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <div id="helpBox">
        <span id="usrText"></span>
      </div>
      <input id="textarea" placeholder="Type Here" maxlength="15">
    </ul>
  </li>
```

Comment: Awesome! That seems to work. I just couldn't find anything to change the css style per line with jquery. I saw the .fontcolor(" ") for js but couldn't figure out how to implement anything like it. Thank you!

Comment: css() change styles in the elements.. but you use $('text') and you don't have element with tag 'text'.. $(".class") or $("#id") or $("tag")

Comment: I was just trying to see if I could grab that variable somehow and do anything with it. I forgot to take that part out before posting.

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)